# lodash isEmpty and has method vs simple check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I can do `if(user) { //do something }` but I've seen people used lodash to do simple checking. I've read lodash's docs about `isEmpty` and `has` methods, but can't figure out why you'd want to use these.

```
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash'; 

if(isEmpty(user)) { //omg why? }
```

Answer (score 38):

`if(user)` will pass for empty Object/Array, but they are empty and should be rejected.

Also `if(user)` will fail for values like `0` or `false` which are totally valid values.

Using `isEmpty()` will take care of such values. Also, it makes code more readable.

Point to note is `isEmpty(1)` will return `true` as `1` is a primitive value and not a data structure and hence should return `true`.

This has been stated in [Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEmpty):

> Checks if value is an empty object, collection, map, or set.

Also as per docs,

> Objects are considered empty if they have no own enumerable string keyed properties.

So if you have an object which does not have non-enumerable properties, its considered as empty. In the below example, `foo` is a part of object `o` and is accessible using `o.foo` but since its non-enumerable, its considered as empty as even `for..in` would ignore it.

```js
var o = Object.create(null);

Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: "Hello World"
})
Object.defineProperty(o, "bar", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: "Testing 123"
});


console.log(o)
for (var k in o) {
  console.log(k)
}

console.log(o.foo)

console.log(_.isEmpty(o))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Note:** This does not mean you should use lodash for such purpose. You can write your own `isEmpty` function.

Following is something that I use:

This will return true for following cases:

- `{}`, `[]`, `""`, `undefined`, `null`, object in above snippet(*no enumerable property*)

```js
function isEmpty(value){
  return  value === undefined ||
          value === null ||
          (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
          (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0)
}
```

Comment: It's just fine to pass 0 or false, why not?

Comment: Point is when you do `if(user)` its read as `if user exists then..`. Now `false` or `0`  are valid values, but JS handles it differently. So when you write `_.isEmpty(variable)` a normal person would read it as `if variable is empty then...`, but a known user would deduce that `variable` is of type `object` and should have some enumerable property and that makes things really easy to understand.

Comment: `Object.keys([null, null, null]) === ["0", "1", "2"]`

Comment: @MrYellow Care to elaborate?

Comment: Some frameworks offer an "isEmpty" which checks contents are truthy. null keys would be considered "empty". When you truncate an array with `arr.length = 10` you end up with an "empty" array which has 10 elements.

Comment: @MrYellow That may be correct, if you notice it, I said "Its something that I use" because I never encountered that case. So thanks for that. But in general, I would not handle `null` as, in my experience `null` is an intentional value and `undefined` is empty.

Comment: This answer was expanded upon here: [Lodash _.isEmpty(value), you might be using it the wrong way. - Medium](https://medium.com/@trmaphi/lodash-isempty-value-you-might-be-using-it-the-wrong-way-d83210d7decf)

Comment: @Yarin Thank you for the credit. However, I would not suggest using `NaN` check for this. NaN is a value which is not empty. Its just used incorrectly. You should create another function isValid which can have that check. But once again, thank you for the credit. Means a lot to me

Comment: @Rajesh good point. I think your function is better anyway

Answer (score 5):

Simple and elegant function for checking the values are empty or not

```
    function isEmpty(value) {
     const type = typeof value;
     if ((value !== null && type === 'object') || type === 'function') {
       const props = Object.keys(value);
        if (props.length === 0 || props.size === 0) { 
          return true;
        } 
      } 
      return !value;
}
```

> Testing the above method

It will return 'true' for all cases below

```
console.log(isEmtpy(null)) 
console.log(isEmtpy(0))
console.log(isEmtpy({}))
console.log(isEmtpy(new Set())
console.log(isEmtpy(Object.create(null))
console.log(isEmtpy(''))
console.log(isEmtpy(() => {}))
console.log(isEmtpy(() => [])
```

Comment: `isEmpty([null, null, null]) === false`